# Remove redundancies in code

Tags: c#, winforms, duplicates, shrink

I'm still new at this so I will try to explain my problem the best I can. English is not my first language so I apologize if I use some terms incorrectly.

I have a 100 line code that is executed every time a button is pressed. My problem is, I have 20 buttons and they all contain the same code (they are only slightly different in means of grabbing info from different source). Is there any way to do this instead of copying the same code too many times.

Basically my code is this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //file data source url
    sourceUrl = ("www.myurl.com")

    //Grab data
    code
    code
    code

   //Store data
    code
    code
    code

   //Write data
    code
    code
    code
    }
```

Every button has the same code except for the "sourceUrl" part. If I want to add more buttons I have to copy>paste the whole code and my application is starting to get HUGE. Is there any way to shrink the code by only having the code once, and then calling an action or method every time the button is pressed. So instead of having 100 line code multiple time, I'll have one line code for each button and one 100 line code on the top that will be the source for that one line code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: create a function handleClick(string url) with the code, then from the handler just call the function with the right url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what functions are for. Use this layout:

```
private void YourFunc(string sourceUrl)
{
    //Grab data
    code

    //Store data
    code

    //Write data
    code
}
```

Now your buttons' event handlers look like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourFunc("www.myurl.com");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourFunc("www.myurl2.com");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps SO guys should make it compulsory for the downvoters to leave comments.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `Tag` property of your buttons to store the source url string and then set, for every button, the same event handler

```
private void buttonCommonHandler_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Button b = sender as Button;
     CommonMethod(b.Tag.ToString());
}

private void CommonMethod(string sourceUrl)
{
   // Execute the common code here....
}
```

You could set the common handler and the Tag using the form designer window or you could do that dynamically mimicking the code prepared for you by the designer in the `InitializeComponent` call

```
button1.Click += buttonCommonHandler;
button1.Tag = "www.myurl.com";
button2.Click += buttonCommonHandler;
button2.Tag = "www.anotherurl.com";
```

Comment: Good solution here. One shared event handler and using the tag attribute to let you easily change the URL via the front-end, without 20 event handlers.

Comment: @Steve  +1 for common handler and `Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is a way. Just make the whole function a function that takes the url as a string parameter. And then call that function from your code behind.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //file data source url
    ProcessData("www.myurl.com");
}

private void ProcessData(string sourceUrl)
{
    //Grab data
    code
    code
    code

    //Store data
    code
    code
    code

    //Write data
    code
    code
    code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use use `CommandName` property, by passing `URL` in every button's `CommandName` property and passing it as a parameter to your `Common Method` to fetch data , So you can create a single function and call it through you `btn_Click` event .

```
<asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="clickMe"   
                        CommandName="put your URL here" OnCommand="button1_Click" />
                        <%--OnClick="button1_Click" />--%>
```

See here we can pass your 'URL' in `CommandName` property ,few things to keep in mind , Here we are using `OnCommand` event rather than `OnClick` event of button , so that we can use 'CommandName' property here .1. [OnCommand MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.oncommand.aspx) 
 2. [Commandname MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandname.aspx)

```
 // private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       private void button1_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {             
         string sourceUrl = Convert.tostring(e.CommandName) 
         // Call function to grab data pass URL as parameter.
          GrabDate (sourceUrl ) ;
```

So now we can get the `URL`  value from button `CommandName` property .

3 . [EventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx)

4 .[CommandEventArgsClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs.aspx)